# How to publishing the Bonjour services in Windows?

Tags: windows, bonjour

I know how to publish a Bonjour service on Mac Os, but I do not know how to do this in windows.

Can somebody help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. For Window, one solution is "install bonjour for window".
2. Then, use C API to develop under window.
3. Please reference,Apple's bonjour SDK page. They provide an SDK for Windows there.